# when we use renameTo() 2 times failed, why?

Tags: java, windows, file, rename

I am using Win7. I use java  to rename a file the 1st time (file.cmptr to file.sql) to do some thing, after that I want to rename it in his old name (file.cmptr)

but this failed, when I rename the files, some times failed to be renamed. It happen randomly.

-some times the 1st file don't change at all and i don't get the operation

-and some times it change to .sql file and I get the operation but the file stay .sql

in my example:

- the 1st time I change the extension:

  ```
  int dotIndex = filechose.getPath().lastIndexOf('.');
  String newpath = filechose.getPath().substring(0, dotIndex);;
  newpath = newpath + ".sql";
  File filefinal = new File(newpath); 
  filechose.renameTo(filefinal);
  String path=newpath;
  ```

after i do the operation with the new file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mysql -u root gestiondestock <"+'"'+path+'"');
```

finally i'm trying to rename the file again

```
File file1 = new File(path);
int dotIndex1 = path.lastIndexOf('.');
String newpath1 = path.substring(0, dotIndex1);
newpath1 = newpath1 + ".computeramg";
File file2 = new File(newpath1); 
file1.renameTo(file2);
```

---

Solved.
it work with wait for i change only this:

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mysql -u root gestiondestock <"+'"'+path+'"');

                 p.waitFor();
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to rename the file the second time?  You say "some times failed" but you don't explain how it fails.

Comment: @DanPuzey some time the file don't rename at all no error

Comment: `renameTo()` as all the other `File` methods doesn't throw Exceptions it just returns `true` or `false` depending on success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are trying to rename the file while it is being using.

You can use waitFor on the mysql process, or you can add the rename using `REN` to the script you are executing. i.e. so it will rename the file when it has finished.

Comment: in this example what is the best to use REN or waitFro ??

Comment: I would do whatever you think is simpler. Most likely, I would use waitFor() is you can and then perform a renameTo(). If this is not an option, you can add it to the script.